# Is this a bug in using Keras with tensorflow Datasets?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Or maybe the tutorial has a typo somewhere. Or maybe there's a bug just in my version (see notes; cannot upgrade online via `pip`). Or maybe I'm doing something wrong. **I'd like to know which and what to do about it.**

[This tensorflow keras tutorial with datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#input_tfdata_datasets) is presented in pieces, but I've assembled them as best I could for this question as follows (note that I've had to make some changes, such as the "import keras layers" statement and adding an `input_shape` to the first layer because the code blows up without it):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras import layers
import numpy as np

print(tf.VERSION)
print(tf.keras.__version__)

data = np.random.random((1000, 32))
labels = np.random.random((1000, 10))

# Instantiates a toy dataset instance:
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        # Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(32,)),

        # Add another:
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),

        # Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
        layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Don't forget to specify `steps_per_epoch` when calling `fit` on a dataset.
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

Full output:

```
1.6.0
2.1.3-tf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-47ae8a0a1bac>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/1134400/Documents/Python/python3/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/1134400/Documents/Python/python3')

  File "C:\Users\1134400\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\1134400\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/1134400/Documents/Python/python3/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)

  File "C:\Users\1134400\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\models.py", line 920, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

  File "C:\Users\1134400\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 1681, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

  File "C:\Users\1134400\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 1508, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

  File "C:\Users\1134400\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 105, in _standardize_input_data
    np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data

  File "C:\Users\1134400\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 105, in <listcomp>
    np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data

AttributeError: 'RepeatDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

**Why isn't this working?** Is there a bug in my version of tensorflow/keras? Is there a bug in my mostly-copy-pasted code?

**Notes:**

1. Versions:

   - Tutorial: The page says `tf.VERSION` is 1.12.0 and `tf.keras.__version__` is 2.1.6-tf.
   - Mine: Output says `tf.VERSION` is 1.6.0 and `tf.keras.__version__` is 2.1.3-tf.
   - I'm behind in my versions.
2. [These notes for Keras 2.2.0](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.2.0) say this:

   > With Keras 2.2.0 and TensorFlow 1.8 or higher, you may fit, evaluate and predict using symbolic TensorFlow tensors

   The tutorial's version is prior to this, so support for tensorflow datasets was obviously prior.
3. [These notes for Keras 2.07](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.0.7) say this:

   > Better support for training models from data tensors in TensorFlow (e.g. Datasets, TFRecords).

   The tutorial's version is newer than this, as is mine, so dataset support should already be present.
4. Using tensorflow for CPU on Windows. Not GPU.
5. There is a restrictive firewall in place on my internet-connected network that (1) I do not control and (2) that does not allow `pip` through, so the simple "use `pip` to upgrade your version" approach is not on the table. Obtaining a new version for offline installation takes some effort, and I won't subject myself to that if I made a mistake
6. Remove this line: `dataset = dataset.repeat()`. The exception changes to `AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'`. It's like it isn't able to use datasets.
7. I don't know what `model.fit(dataset, ...)` is doing. In my version, the first two positional arguments to `model.fit(...)` are `x` and `y`. The dataset was constructed with a tuple, so is passing the dataset as the a single positional argument supposed to implicitly unpack both features and labelsfrom it?

Comment: I have TF 1.10.1 and Keras 2.1.6-tf and your code runs fine for me. So I think its down to the versions. The simplest thing you can try is to add an iterator to your code. Maybe the earlier versions do not support a direct dataset object without an iterator to be fed to model.fit. So instead of feeding dataset to model.fit, feed dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() and see if it works. As far as updating your packages go, have you considered using a virtual environment and installing the new version to test your code over there?

Comment: "So I think its down to the versions." Good to know. Tried iterator: `itr = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() | features_itr, labels_itr = itr.get_next() | ... | model.fit(x=features_itr, y=labels_itr, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)`. New output error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'`. It really wants `ndim`. As for making a virtual environment, how would that help? I'd need to find and request installation of virtualization software, and I'm still behind the firewall, so I still can't get the update.

Comment: You need not break  it down to a tuple using get next. Feeding the defined one shot iterator directly would also be fine for future purposes. I meant creating a virtual python environment with virtualenv and then doing the offline thing since you had talked about not wanting to affect anything by making a mistake!

Comment: Switched to simply `itr = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()...`model.fit(itr, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)` and got this: `AttributeError: 'Iterator' object has no attribute 'ndim'`. Same error, different object. And I see what you thought about the virtual environment. I was trying to say that I didn't want to go through the process of getting an offline installation (simply put, it's a hassle and could take a while), but if the problem was a typo, then I fix move on. Doesn't look like that's going to be an option though, so hassle it is :/. Thanks for checking.

Comment: thats tough. But yeah I think its necessary. Especially TF version 2.0 is on the horizon now. So it would be good to update things anyway :)

Comment: @JohnCox did you end up finding a solution to this? What was your work-around? My versions are TF 1.6.0 and Keras 2.0.6 and I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: @jeet.m Not that I remember. I haven't touched that code since not long after I posted the question. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I updated `tensorflow` to `2.1.0` and importing `keras` not directly but `import tensorflow.keras`. Doing this the same broken code using `Dataset` now works